# What types other than IEEE-754 floating-point types define relational operators non-transitively or equality non-reflexively

Tags: floating-point, programming-languages, equals

It would seem helpful for a programming language to define an equality operator such that for all combinations of types where it compiles, it will define an equivalence relation.  It would likewise be helpful to define relational operators in such a fashion that they define a full ordering, so that such operators might safely be used for purposes like sorting.

IEEE-754 floating-point types abide by neither of those expectations.  I recall sets in Pascal behaved as equivalence relations when tested for equality, but defined `<=` and `>=` in such a way that `a<=b` and `b<=a` could both be false (e.g. `a` is [1,2] and `b` is [1,3]).  What other types are there in noteworthy programming languages which define relational operators to be non-transitive, even when applied to things of the same type?  Are there any which likewise define equality non-transitively?  What about non-reflexively?  Is the requirement of non-reflexive comparison unique to IEEE-754 floating-point values, or is it shared by other types?  Are there any notable programming languages which use IEEE-754 for floating-point calculations, but provide intrinsic equality-test and relational operators which obey the rules for equivalence relations and complete orderings?

Comment: In recent OCaml version, `compare x y = 0` between floats `x` and `y` is an equivalence relation. It identifies `-0.0` and `0.0`, but it places `nan` below finite values, so that `compare 0.0 nan` is `1` and `compare nan 0.0` is `-1`. The binary operator `=` between floats behaves as someone familiar with IEEE 754 would expect.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: That sounds like `x.Equals(y)` in .NET, though not Java.  I'm curious, though, as to whether IEEE-754 floats are unique in their non-reflexive comparison behavior, and how common non-transitive behaviors are.  As noted, sets in at least some Pascal dialects use `<=` and `>=` in a fashion which doesn't match relational operators; I'm not sure what other data types behave oddly with those.  From a language design perspective, I've been thinking it would be good to have separate "strict IEEE" floating-point types as well as rankable types, with the rules that...

Comment: ...the strict types could only be compared to things of matching strict types, and the `<` and `==` operators would not compile with any other combination of arguments where they would behave as anything other than equivalence relations.  So, for example, a comparison between a `long` and `real` [64-bit] should either test that both `(double)l==d` and `d==floor(d)`, or else be rejected by the compiler.  The big difficulty I see is IEEE comparison rules, which I would think would best be isolated in their own separate universe.  Would that seem a reasonable design?

Comment: Do you exclude comparison of heterogenneous types (like an int32 vs a float32)? Nan apart, this also is a common cause of non transitivity...

Comment: @aka.nice: The situation would be analogous to the `long` and `double` situation mentioned above [which I slipped up on, btw], except that an easier way to achieve the same result in the case of `int` and `float` would be to convert both values to `double` [btw, for `double` vs `long`, it should probably be something like `(double)l==d && (long)(double)l == l`].  BTW, I wish languages would make distinction between perfect casts (e.g. `int` to `long`), information-reducing casts (e.g. `double` to `float`), and information-assuming casts (e.g. `float` to `double`), and...

Comment: ...let code specify whether particular parameters to functions or operators should accept certain kinds of cast implicitly.  For something like `==`, information-assuming and information-reducing casts should both be rejected; for something like a graphical `moveTo` method, both kinds of cast should be implicitly accepted.  Implicit information-assuming casts performed on the result of another cast should probably be rejected [e.g. if `someField` is `double`, then `someField = (float)Math.Sqrt(something);` would likely as not a be a mistake by someone who thought it was `float`).

Comment: @supercat cast to double: yes unless you deal with int64... In Squeak/Pharo Smalltalk, I arranged to have all mixed arithmetic comparison operations to deal with exact representation, rather than converting the exact value to an inexact (float) representation first. http://bugs.squeak.org/view.php?id=3374 . Thus (1/10)=0.1 is false (an exact fraction compared to a float). This was done in Lisp and probably Scheme long before Smalltalk http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lcl50/aug/aug-170.html .

Comment: @aka.nice: I'm not particularly familiar with Smalltalk; is there any way of storing the concept "one tenth" in a variable, or can it not exist outside the context of an expression?  Also, would fractions participate in an equivalence relation?  Also, what would be the result of a comparison `(1/2)==0.5`?

Comment: @supercat a Fraction is an Object with a numerator and a denominator (reduced) which are Integer (posible LargeInteger of arbitrary length). They are kind of Number, so yes they participate in equivalence relation for =. Thus the poor man database named Dictionary - a HashedMap - just works. We decided that (1/2)=0.5 shall return true. But AFAIR, in some languages like Scheme, this option is implementation defined: one can decide to always answer false when the arithmetic type differ - because every float is potentially inexact, it cannot be compared to an exact number - int or rational

Comment: @aka.nice: I can certainly understand a rationale for regarding floating-point values as representing a set of equivalence classes disjoint from any others; having them do so would not preclude their participation in a "global" equivalence relation.  My main points of curiosity are (1) whether the lack of a defined equivalence relation and consistent ranking are peculiar to IEEE-754, and (2) whether any languages decide to "buck the trend" and have relational operators regard floating-point types as having consistent ranking and equivalence relations.  I know Python bucked the trend...

Comment: ...with its integer division and modulus operators (hooray!) but from what I understand its floating-point equality test is broken in the usual IEEE-754 fashion, wreaking havoc on float-keyed collections.  I wonder if any languages have bucked the trend with their comparison operators, and what the consequences of such a decision have been.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55529/discussion-between-aka-nice-and-supercat).

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any notable programming languages which use IEEE-754 for floating-point calculations, but provide intrinsic equality-test and relational operators which obey the rules for equivalence relations and complete orderings?

By definition, if `x <= NaN` and `NaN <= x` are anything but false, then it isn't IEEE-754 arithmetic! The 2008 revision defines a `totalOrder` predicate, such that `totalOrder(-0,+0) == true` and `totalOrder(+0,-0) == false`, and `NaN`s either precede `-Inf` or succeed `+Inf` depending on their sign bit. However I'm not aware of any languages that currently implement it.

UPDATE: C [TS 18661-1:2014](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=63146) ([free draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1676.pdf)) does offer a `totalorder` function, but I don't know of any implementations that offer it yet.

Comment: IEEE-754 requires that languages *provide* some form of relational operators which behave a certain way. I am unaware of it saying that the language cannot provide *additional* operators.  Nor am I aware of anything that would mandate that any particular symbols be used for particular operators.  Correct me if I'm wring, but I am unaware of anything in IEEE-754 which would preclude a language using the character sequence `X.IEEE_LT.Y` to test the IEEE-754 less-than relation, and `X.LT.Y` to test a ranking relation; the only requirement I know of is that the first operator must exist.

Comment: That is certainly correct, though I don't know of any languages which have used such an approach.

Comment: I wonder why languages don't nicely support any intrinsic ordering relations? Sorting arrays of numbers would seem like an operation which is both common and likely to be performance-critical, so having to jump through hoops to get a ranking would seem inefficient.

Comment: Well, you can always reinterpret the bit pattern as an int, and sort it that way.

Comment: Few languages include a compiler intrinsic to perform such reinterpretation, and use of such an approach (especially in compilers without an intrinsic) would make it difficult for a compiler to use an instruction for such a test if hardware happened to add one. A compiler-intrinsic ordering operation could be implemented by the compiler to use bit-hackery when required, but use hardware when available. Further, languages influence hardware design; in the 1980s and early 1990s when Borland compilers used Kahan's recommended numerical evaluation approach, hardware was optimized for that.

Comment: Since then, after Java and Microsoft both decided to favor lower-precision semantics, hardware vendors have pushed to deprecate the more precise maths.

Comment: By more precise maths, you mean the x87 registers? I don't think too many people will be sad to see then end of the 80bit float (especially the "unintentional" ones that generate SO questions). Give me SSE, AVX and native fma's any day.

Comment: The 80-bit floats worked very nicely when using a compiler that supported them properly (as Borland's compilers tended to do from my experience). IMHO, 99% of the ire against those types is a result of compilers which failed to provide a user-accessible type that could hold intermediate results, or would arbitrarily round values when spilling FPU registers. Such semantics are terrible, but I don't blame the 80-bit format. Further, there can IMHO be some semantic advantages to a language including a "universal" numeric primitive to which all others can be *losslessly* converted.